# Configuring Azure Application Insights for Sitecore 8.0

Tags: application-insights

How can I configure Application Insights for Sitecore 8.0?

I can not find any How-to guides for 8.0. I found a How-to for 8.2, but I would like to know if Sitecore 8.0 support Application Insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Application Insights on Sitecore is only supported using the Azure Toolkit, which requires Sitecore XP 8.2 Update-1 (rev. 161115).

Source: [Microsoft Azure Services compatibility table](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/682999)

Answer (score 3):

According to the official documentation:

> There are two ways to enable application monitoring for Azure App Services hosted applications:
>
> - Agent-based application monitoring (ApplicationInsightsAgent).
> - Manually instrumenting the application through code

For Sitecore 8.0 your only option is **Agent-based application monitoring (ApplicationInsightsAgent).**

> This method is the easiest to enable, and no advanced configuration is required. It is often referred to as "runtime" monitoring. For Azure App Services we recommend at a minimum enabling this level of monitoring and then based on your specific scenario you can evaluate whether more advanced monitoring through manual instrumentation is needed.

To enable that, go to your App Service, select **Application Insights** blade, then enable the extension:
[image]

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, my client used a classic Cloud Service, but I will check:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/cloudservices